# Cross product implying vectors are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, cross-product

For 3-D vectors $a$, $b$ prove:

$a \times b = a − b$ implies $a = b$

I've been working on this question for a while and have no idea how to solve it, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That would imply $b-a \bot a, b-a \bot b$.

Comment: This question doesn't appear to make sense. If $a=b$ then $a-b=0$ but say $b=2a$ then $a\times b=0\neq a-b$ so the two things are not equivalent.

Comment: @SuzuHirose: That doesn't contradict the result, since $0=a\times b=-a$ would then make $a=0,$ and so $b=2a=0,$ whence $a=b$.

Comment: Yes, but it's a silly question because the cross product is always perpendicular to both $b$ and $a$, so it's never equal to a sum of $a$ and $b$ except if they are the same, but $a$ and $b$ may be different and still have a zero cross product with a non-zero difference between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @SuzuHirose If $a-b$ is perpendicular to $a$ and $b$ then it must be zero.

Comment: This really does not make any sense, if $a=b$ in the first place, then $a-b=0$ obviously, so what does the whole $a\times b=a-b$ statement even mean? I'll post an answer to the question anyway since this is getting silly.

Comment: We have $(a-b)\cdot(a-b)=(a-b)\cdot(a\times b)=a\cdot(a\times b)-b\cdot(a\times b)=0-0=0$. Hence $a-b=0$.

Comment: @SuzuHirose You are supposed to assume that all you know is $a\times b$ equals $a-b$. They may or may not both equal $0$. When you reason around how they actually do both equal $0$, you are already using more knowledge than is given in the statement, and you are on your way to proving the claim.

Comment: @2'59'2 I understand that you do not agree that the phrasing of this question is absolutely daft. I've said enough about this topic now, so this will be my last response to comments here.

Comment: @SuzuHirose Fair enough that you are not returning. But as I read your comments, I feel as though you understand "implies" to mean $\iff$. But "implies" only means $\implies$. So for example your first comment with "If $a=b$..." is not relevant to OP's question.

Comment: I think it is silly to describe the question as silly.

Answer (score 3):

- If $a, b$ are linearly independent, then $a\times b$ is orthogonal to
  both $a$ and $b$, hence cannot be a linear combination of $a$ and $b$.
- If $a, b$ are linearly dependent that is one is a scalar multiple of
  the other, then $a\times b=0$ and $a\times b = a-b\Rightarrow a=b$.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to show that $a = 0$ if and only if $b = 0$, so we may assume both are non-zero.

Now, $a \times b = a - b$ implies $(a \times b) \times b = a \times b$, but this is only possible if $a\times b = 0$, so that $a = cb$ for some scalar $c$.

Plugging this back into the original equation, we get $(c - 1)b = 0$. But since $b$ is non-zero by assumption, we get $c = 1$ and so $a = b$.

Comment: "*this is only possible if $a \times b=0$*" $\,$ Then just substitute that on the LHS of the original equation.

Comment: @dxiv good point, that's quite a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that $a \perp (a \times b)$ and $b \perp (a \times b)$, then
\begin{align*}
  \|a \times b\|^2
  &=
  (a \times b) \cdot (a \times b)
  \\
  &=
  (a - b) \cdot (a \times b)
  \\
  &=
  a \cdot (a \times b)
  -
  b \cdot (a \times b)
  \\
  &=
  0 + 0 = 0.
\end{align*}
That is, $a - b = a \times b = \vec{0}$.
And therefore, $a = b$.

---

In general, if $c \perp a$ and $c \perp b$, then $c$ is perpendicular to the whole space spawned by $a$ and $b$ (vectors of the form $\alpha a + \beta b$). In this case, this means $(a \times b) \perp (a \times b)$.

Answer (score 1):

$a\times b$ is a vector which is perpendicular to the plane containing $a$ and $b$. However, a linear combination of $a$ and $b$, i.e. $ma+nb$, is a vector which lies *on* the plane of $a$ and $b$. This simply implies that the only possible case is that both vectors, i.e. $a\times b$ and $a - b$,are null. Hence, $a-b = 0 \implies \vec a=\vec b$.

Answer (score 0):

The cross-product of two vectors is orthogonal to those vectors.

$(a\times b) = a-b\\
(a-b)\cdot(a\times b) = (a-b)\cdot(a-b)\\
a\cdot(a\times b) - b\cdot(a\times b) = \|a-b\|^2\\
0-0 = \|a-b\|^2\\
a-b = 0\\
a=b$

Answer (score -1):

The three-dimensional cross product of two vectors, $a \times b$, is always orthogonal to both of its vectors, in other words perpendicular to them, so it is never equal to $a$ or $b$ multiplied by any scalar except zero.

In other words, if you have an equation
$$a\times b = ia+jb$$
where $i$ and $j$ are scalars, the only possible answers are either or both of the conditions $i=j=0$, or $i=-j$ and $a=b$, since the right side of this equation must equal zero.

Just adding my opinion, but the way this problem is phrased seems completely mad. Surely it should say "The condition $a\times b=a-b$ is only satisfied if $a=b$." The whole "implies" part of the question seems to be deliberately perverse phrasing.

Comment: In mathematics, “A implies B” ([implication](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional)) is an established synonym of “A is satisfied only if B is satisfied” or “B is a necessary condition for A”, and there is absolutely nothing “complete mad” or “deliberately perverse” about the phrasing of the question.